# How to write in terminal commands previously used?

Tags: linux, command

As simple as that. My programming teacher do it and I want to know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not trying to solve programming. And not using a puter/shell doesn't mean it's trying to solve a programming problem

Comment: Sorry but the question really helps me.

Comment: Yes and it would certainly help me if somebody would get me something to drink. Sadly doesn't make it anymore or any less on topic though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to press up/down key.

Here you have a [terminal guide for beginners](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide/).

Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks, my question feels a little bit silly but really helps when I'm using Linux terminal.